# Translation is not working in Magento 2 cloud environment

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to traslate "The coupon code couldn't be applied. Verify the coupon code and try again." error message from  vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/CouponManagement.php.

so added the translation in app/design/vendor_theme/i18n/en_US.csv folder it worked in local but in the cloud instance it not worked.

so i added translation in the app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Quote/i18n/en_US.csv. it worked in local but in the cloud instance it is also not worked.

what am missing here? how can i fix this issue?

thanks.